How to write WebActivity Ouput to a Kusto table in ADF
The output of my web activity is a json file.
I want to dump the entire json into single column kusto table. (likely do a .set-or-replace) in azure data factory pipeline.
So, my pipeline has a web activity, next I need to dump the output to kusto table


Take a web activity and give the required API in the URL.


Connect the web activity with the copy activity.

In source settings of copy activity, add a dummy source dataset with one row data.




Add an additional column in source setting and give the value for that column as dynamic content @string(activity('Web1').output)

Add the azure data explorer dataset in sink dataset.

In mapping settings of copy activity, add only the required mapping.



This way you can copy the output of web activity to a column in Kusto table.

the output of a web activity is a json document and not string. so, copying this data to kusto is failing

@string() is used to convert the Json data to string. Check the expression once. @string(activity('Web1').output). If you are giving the same, can you share the error message here
